# Blender render preview black background

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine

Blender render preview (cycles) show black background, the object is not clearly visible.
[image]

Comment: Try a different lamp, and make sure it's positioned the right way? You can also check to make sure cycles is taking your lamp into account.

Comment: how to add another lamp?

Comment: I think you're using a sun lamp. It's pretty weak and only used for large environments to give everything a soft accent. Locally, you might want to change it to a directional light. Just change the lamp type. Don't add more light than you need to right now. Just go to the lamp tab, and change the lamp type and choose the one that works.

Comment: lamp has nothing to do with the black background.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do lighting in Cycles is to use emission planes. First, add a plane with **Shift + A** > **Mesh** > **Plane**. Then, rotate the plane to face a significant point in your scene or at your object:

[image: Added plane]

Next, add an emission material to the plane by going under the **Material** tab and clicking **New**. Set the material's **Surface** to **Emission** and give it a **Strength** of at least **15** or so.

[image: Emission material settings]

You can use as many of these planes as you want, but try to add only as many lights as you would need in the real world.